# Translational and Rotational Energy in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity

In non-relativistic classical mechanics:
$$\tag{1}
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{KE}&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_i m_i v_i^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i m_i (\vec{v}_{cm}+\vec{v}_{i,rel})^2 \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_i m_i (v_{cm}^2+2\vec{v}_{cm}\cdot\vec{v}_{i,rel}+v_{i,rel}^2)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $i$ represents a particle in the system of mass $m_i$ and velocity $\vec{v}_i$.  Here, $\vec{v}_{cm}$ is the center of mass velocity, and $\vec{v}_{i,rel}$ is the velocity of $i$ relative to the center of mass.  Since $\sum_i \vec{v}_{i,rel}=0$,
$$\tag{2}
\text{KE}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_i m_i \right) v_{cm}^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_im_iv_{i,rel}^2
$$
Thus, almost trivially, we get the famous statement that the total kinetic energy of a system can be decomposed into a translational kinetic energy of the center of mass and a rotational kinetic energy around the center of mass.  However, notice that this all depended on the kinetic energy of particle $i$ being linearly proportional to $v_i^2$, which is not the case in special relativity.

My question is this: Can a similar statement like "the total kinetic energy of a system can be decomposed into a translational kinetic energy of the center of mass and a rotational kinetic energy around the center of mass" be made in special relativity?  Of course, there are no rigid bodies in special relativity, and there is no 4-vector analog to center of mass, but that is of no importance here.

Additional question: It can be shown (in non-relativistic classical mechanics) that if you had masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ that if an explosion releasing energy $U$ blasted these masses away from each other, the number $U$ is invariant under a Galilean transformation.  Is it invariant under a Lorentz transformation?

Comment: I don't have more time to answer this and the book I tried to look it up in lists this as a practice problem! What first comes to mind: Assuming the momentum in frame 1 zero and the kinetic energy is $E_1$, you can use the energy-momentum invariant to say $E_2^2-(P_2 c)^2=E_1^2$. Perhaps this is in the form you need?

Comment: "There are no rigid bodies and there is no 4-vector analog of the center of mass),but that is of no importance here"- Care to explain why?

Comment: The non-relativistic derivation of the statement "the total kinetic energy of a system can be decomposed into a translational kinetic energy of the center of mass and a rotational kinetic energy around the center of mass" doesn't require a rigid body even though it is frequently applied to it.  And in special relativity, for a massive system, a center of momentum frame can always be defined.

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/564500/226902