# Relativistic velocity of the center of momentum frame

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, reference-frames

In Newtonian mechanics the expression for the velocity of the center of momentum frame is $v_{CM}=\frac{\sum_i m_i v_i}{\sum_i m_i}$, where $v_i$ is the velocity of the particle $i$ in the lab frame.

Is there any expression similar to this one in special relativity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\vec v_{CM}}{c}=\frac{ \sum \vec p_{i}c }{ \sum E_i }=\frac{\vec P_{SYS}c}{E_{SYS}}$.

On an energy-momentum diagram, 
this says add up all of the 4-momenta to get the 4-momentum of the system.

The spatial velocity of the system 4-momentum is essentially the slope
of that 4-momentum vector:
the ratio of the spatial-components (the vector sum of relativistic-momenta)
and the temporal-components (the sum of the relativistic energies).

For massive particles, this becomes

$\frac{ v_{CM}}{c}=\frac{\sum m_i c^2\sinh\theta_i }{\sum m_i c^2\cosh\theta_i}=\frac{\sum \gamma_i m_i v_i c}{\sum \gamma_i m_i c^2}$

or
$\vec v_{CM}=
\frac{\sum \gamma_i m_i \vec v_i }{\sum \gamma_i m_i}$

Comment: These $\gamma_i$ are in the lab frame, right?

Comment: Yes, the $\gamma_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v_i/c)^2}}$ are in the lab frame.